# Clion: define macros/functions in project file

Tags: macros, cmake, clion

I have a macro defined in a .cmake file on usr/share/Cmake/Modules/
as below.

```
macro ( debug string )    
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
        message(WARNING ${string})
    else()
    endif()
endmacro()
```

Currently I am doing:

```
include(file.cmake)
```

which allows me to use the macro. I would like to be able to use it in Clion but I don't want to pollute the source files of my project. I have noticed that one can pass value for variables for the build configurations. I was wondering if there is any way of doing a similar thing with macros and have Clion load a set of default macros.

Comment: You can set cache variables on the command line, but macros are not variables in CMake. If this is needed as part of your build process (and you use the macro in your CMakeLists), then how does a single include pollute anything? (IMHO not including it and relying on injection via command line is even worse, since the CMakeLists will break if you don't do that). Also, if this is a custom cmake script, then `usr/share/Cmake/Modules/` seems like a terrible location. Keep it with the project, or the build will break on another machine.

Comment: well I thought my example would demonstrate the type of macros I am referring to. These macros have nothing to do with the build routine which is why including them in the main routine feels a bit inappropriate. They are just handy tools that I would like to use but don't want to pass them to other developers. As they won't need it.

Comment: CMake is a tool to manage the build process, so IMHO any CMake macros are inherently related to the build. To make any use of them, you need to invoke them from the CMakeLists, which means you will need to edit it. Doing that, you set yourself up to eventually forget about it, and accidentally commit something that will break the build. Furthermore, you never know what may be useful for someone else. Instead, provide 2 variants of the macro, one functional, one that does nothing, and add an option (or variable) that will let you select between them.